# I don't know why my console always outputs the same thing

Tags: javascript, while-loop, addition

I was given this simple scenario: “Write a program that simulates the rolling of two dice. Keep rolling the dice UNTIL the sum of the dice is either a 7 OR an 11. Your program should display the results of each roll."

It's very easy, I know. But the sum of each print is always the same and it's not adding properly. Probably just not seeing something right, but I'm a mega-beginner.

NOTE- the write() function just displays text on a screen in this case.
Here is my code:

```
var die1 = randomNumber(1, 6);
var die2 = randomNumber(1, 6);
var sum = die1 + die2;
while (!(sum == 7 || sum == 11)) {
  die1 = randomNumber(1,6);
  die2 = randomNumber(1,6);
  write("Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + ", sum is " + sum);
}
write("Done.");
```

Comment: Inside of your `while` loop, you are recomputing the values of your dice (by rerolling them). Is there another variable that you should be recomputing as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to recalculate the `sum` inside of the while loop:

```js
var die1 = randomNumber(1, 6);
var die2 = randomNumber(1, 6);
var sum = die1 + die2;
while (!(sum == 7 || sum == 11)) {
  die1 = randomNumber(1,6);
  die2 = randomNumber(1,6);
  //  FIX: recalculate sum
  sum = die1 + die2;
  write("Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + ", sum is " + sum);
}
write("Done.");
```

---

Also it would be cleaner with a do-while loop:

```js
var die1, die2, sum;
do {
  die1 = randomNumber(1,6);
  die2 = randomNumber(1,6);
  sum = die1 + die2;
  write("Rolled " + die1 + " and " + die2 + ", sum is " + sum);
} while(!(sum == 7 || sum == 11));
write("Done.");
```

**Note**: It is also depend on logic written inside randomNumber() function.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to understand this more. If `sum` is a global variable, why would I need to call it again in the while loop? And I never learned about do-while loops, I will look more into them! Thank you.

Comment: Because `sum` is a variable, it will always be the same value if you don't assign it. In your loop, you are checking `sum` again and again without updating it, so the loop will be stuck forever.